# how to get URL from ACTION_SEND?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

My app is registering an intent to receive URLs **so when the user shares a url, my app will be in the list of apps.**

```
<intent-filter
    android:label="my app">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

-

in my MainActivity's onCreate() method:

```
String action = intent.getAction();
if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_SEND)) {
    Uri data = intent.getData();
    String s = data.toString();
    output.setText(s); //output: a TextView that holds the URL
}
```

-

**The problem I got is**: data is null which is strange. Since this code works perfectly with `ACTION_VIEW`. However, it didn't work with `ACTION_SEND`.

**How could I modify it to work?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try

```
String action = intent.getAction(); 
if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_SEND) && intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)) { 
    String s = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT); 
    output.setText(s); //output: a TextView that holds the URL 
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Just one more question: why do I need to check if `Intent.hasExtra()`?

Comment: @iturki I just think it'e better to check whether the data exists before retrieving it. Avoid annoying NullPointerException.

Comment: Does this get triggered each time the user navigates to a new URL in the browser?