# Why doesn't my app receive Intents?

Tags: android, android-intent

i'm trying my app receive data shared by other apps. I.e. when somebody send a youtube link via Whatsapp, Youtube app can receive it and open to show.

I set this at the manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.app.MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTask" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And this code is into MainActivity onCreate method:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String action = intent.getAction();
String type = intent.getType();

if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equalsIgnoreCase(action) && type != null) {
    if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
        String codigoIn = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
        if (codigoIn!=null) Toast.makeText(context, codigoIn, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I try to test sending myself links via Hangouts. When I click on link, the chooser only show Chrome and Internet navigators.

Please, what's wrong? Thank you very much

**UPDATE: SOLVED**

I already solved. I was very lost. I should not use the category ACTION_SEND but ACTION_VIEW. Now, Manifest is:

```
        <intent-filter android:label="my app">
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:host="myHost.com" />
            <data android:host="www.myHost.com" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

And I put at Activity -> onResume method:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();

    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)){
        String dato = intent.getData().toString();
        Intent nuevoIntent = new Intent(context, Resultado.class);
        nuevoIntent.putExtra("codigo", dato);
        startActivity(nuevoIntent);
    }
```

I hope it's useful to someone. It took two days to fix

Comment: You have to ensure `action` `category` and `data` of yours matches those `Hangouts` `WhatsApp` or `Youtobe` sent, haven't you?

Comment: @SilentKnight possibly I'm not understanding how this system works. Everywhere I read that `action = SEND`, `category = DEFAULT` and `data = TEXT / PLAIN`, and that's how I put it. When this works, I will put more filters as `android: host = "www.myHost.com"`

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676397/how-to-get-url-from-action-send

Comment: @Pibs try adding internet permission too

Comment: Internet permission set, the application uses the Internet from day one

Comment: @Pibs don't use "solved". Instead write as answer, so you can accept it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676397/how-to-get-url-from-action-send/9676543#9676543) :

```
String action = intent.getAction(); 
if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_SEND) && intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)) { 
    String s = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT); 
    Toast.makeText(context, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```