# How to get data in editText from others app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to get data from other apps to my app and fill links in the editText

```
 This is my manifests
   <activity
        android:name=".PostActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>

  I have 2 editext in PostActivity
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/post_title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/borders"
    android:hint="@string/add_title"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
   />



<EditText
    android:id="@+id/post_description"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/borders"
    android:hint="@string/start_writing"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
```

if you did not understant me than here's an example; when you share youtube video to social media like facebook, twitter, reddit. it goes directly to postactivity and the link apper in editext. If you help me thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get URL from ACTION\_SEND?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676397/how-to-get-url-from-action-send)

Answer (score 0):

Inside onCreate() of your PostActivity try this:

```
String action = intent.getAction(); 
if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_SEND)){
    if(intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)){ 
        String shareTxt = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT); 
        postTitle.setText(shareTxt); 
    } 
}
```